# The flashing red light is treated like a stop sign

Tags: traffic, alberta

Does the flashing red light eventually turn into a steady red light before it changes to green? If so, does it always happen this way? Thank you!

"[Drivers facing a flashing red traffic control light must stop before the stop line or crosswalk. If there is no stop line or crosswalk, drivers must stop before the intersection. Drivers should proceed only when it is safe and after yielding the right-of way. The flashing red light is treated like a stop sign.](https://www.alberta.ca/traffic-control-signals.aspx#:%7E:text=Drivers%20facing%20a%20flashing%20red,treated%20like%20a%20stop%20sign.)"

Comment: In the US, a flashing red light never changes at all, it just stays flashing red forever.  It is just like a permanently placed stop sign, but easier to see.  I am not sure if Canada is the same but I would assume so.

Comment: (Technically, it might change eventually - if it was flashing because it is a regular traffic signal that was out of order, and eventually gets fixed; or in some places when regular traffic signals switch to flashing red during late night hours.  But it certainly doesn't change on a regular cycle.)

Comment: Legislation tag would be good.

Comment: I am able to imagine "flashing-red", on a light where green-for-"go" is also a possibility, used as a replacement for for "yellow". I'm not aware of anywhere in the U.S. that this convention is used...

Comment: Maurice, do you want to know whether it changes to red by itself, or whether it changes to red before green after the maintenance workers fix the traffic lights?

Comment: @NateEldredge switching to flashing every night is pretty regular.  There must be some provision for getting them out of that phase and back to normal operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the flashing red light eventually turn into a steady red light
> before it changes to green?

Not really.

**Fail Mode For Regular Stoplights**

A flashing red light is usually a default mode of a traffic light system when the control system is broken, or the power grid is down. In these cases, it returns to its usual red-yellow-green mode when the system is back up and running.

[image]

**Visibility Enhancing Red Only Flashing Red Lights**

But, sometimes a permanently flashing red light with no other colors is deployed in addition to, or instead of, a stop sign, at intersections where stop sign visibility has been a problem. In these cases there is never a solid red light, or a light of any other color. It looks like this:

[image]

or like this:

[image]

(Obviously, none of these still images actually shows the flashing in action, you have to use your imagination.)

Comment: FWIW, over here in Germany, traffic lights don't flash in red. They may be switched off or flash yellow, and in both cases this is as if the traffic light did not exist. Most traffic lights have normal signs in addition, and they are then in force. Level railway crossings flash red, and that is not just a stop sign but a "don't cross, train is closeby"

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX What happens when the usual traffic light network's operation is disrupted by a severe storm or power outage?

Comment: @ohwilleke you assume they are networked! Germany is very backwards! I would guess they turn off or flash yellow as cbeleites said

Comment: I lived in a town where the main street turned traffic signals into two-way stops late at night. The main thoroughfare direction got a flashing yellow, while side streets got a flashing red. You had to be extremely careful because people out of town would wrongly assume the perpendicular direction was would stop.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your detailed answers!

Comment: @ohwilleke: without power, the traffic lights are off. Just as many of them are regularly switched off during the night. A traffic light that is on "overrides" right of way by signs. But whenever they are off, the signs are in force. An intersection that is important enough to have a traffic light during day time will have additional signs that unambiguously say who has right of way and who has to yield when the traffic light is off. Here's an example image https://land-der-erfinder.de/100-jahre-ampel/ where you can see the right of way sign next to the traffic light.

Comment: "without power, the traffic lights are off." Most U.S. traffic lights have battery backups. "Just as many of them are regularly switched off during the night." Wild! You wouldn't even find that in one gas station and one diner town with just one stoplight in the U.S.